# pandas groupby one column and then groupby another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`,

```
code    id    amount
BB10    531   20
BB10    531   30
BB10    532   50
BR11    631   10
BR11    632   5
IN20    781   10
IN20    781   20
IN20    781   30
```

I want to first `groupby` `df` using `code` and get the total `amount` within each group,

```
df.groupby('code')['amount'].agg('sum')
```

then I like to know the percentage of `amount` for a specific `id` within a specific `code` group, e.g. for `531` its `amount` is `50` within `BB10`, with a `amount` percentage of `50%`; the result df should look like,

```
code    id    amount    pct
BB10    531   50        50%
BB10    532   50        50%
BR11    631   10        66.7%
BR11    632   5         33.3%
IN20    781   60        100%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate by both columns `sum`, then get total per `code` divide `amount`, multiple by `100` and round:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['code','id'], as_index=False)['amount'].sum()
df1['pct']=df1['amount'].div(df1.groupby('code')['amount'].transform('sum')).mul(100).round(1)
print (df1)
   code   id  amount    pct
0  BB10  531      50   50.0
1  BB10  532      50   50.0
2  BR11  631      10   66.7
3  BR11  632       5   33.3
4  IN20  781      60  100.0
```

Last if need percentages convert values to strings and add `%`:

```
df1['pct'] = df1['pct'].astype(str) + '%'
print (df1)
   code   id  amount     pct
0  BB10  531      50   50.0%
1  BB10  532      50   50.0%
2  BR11  631      10   66.7%
3  BR11  632       5   33.3%
4  IN20  781      60  100.0%
```